# Bazel + Fastlane?

Tags: ios, xcode, bazel, fastlane

Is it possible to integrate Fastlane with Bazel (or vice versa)? The non-mobile part of our org uses Bazel for build, and I'd like to be consistent on mobile. However Fastlane provides a lot of stuff aimed at mobile that Bazellane does not. Bazel is for built + test, whereas Fastlane also provides solutions for release/deployment.

Is it possible (or advisable) to call Bazel build from within Fastlane? Or perhaps call Fastlane from within Bazel for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel is like an interpreter for a language, which allows you to define **rules** - functions which may have a set of inputs, an action, and a set of outputs.

I am not familiar with Fastlane, but it is surely possible to write a rule which will produce you an artifact. The only requirement is that your set of **outputs** must be clearly defined (hardcoded in a rule) - in other words, you can not write a rule which will "unzip whatever is in this archive to this folder", because you have to define a set of outputs.

[Rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html) doc page is the best place to start.